# Looking for an advice regarding finding the best time series model

Tags: time-series, arima, model-selection, seasonality

I have weekly time series data, which looks like follows:

[image]

The data seems to be non-stationary. Then I took the first difference of the data. Now the data seems to be more stationary.

[image: ![enter image description here]

After that, I used the `auto.arima` function to first differenced data to find the best model. It was suggested a `seasonal ARIMA` model.

```
Best model: ARIMA(0,0,0)(1,0,0)[52] with zero mean
```

However, as you can see based on the time series plot for the first differenced data, there seems to be no seasonal trend in the data.

So what should I do now ? Should I follow the results of `auto.arima`? Or else, are there any alternative path that I can follow ?

To check whether there is any seasonality in the first differenced data, I again took the seasonal difference of the first differenced data(differencing the first differenced data by taking lag=52). Following is the time series plot for the seasonal differenced data of the first differenced data.

[image]

For me, there is no any significant difference between the time series plot of the first differenced data and the time series plot of the seasonal differenced data of the first differenced data.

**********Update*********

This is the plot that I obtained using `seasonplot` function in `foreacast` package for first differenced data.
[image]

There seems to be a slight peak around week 24-25. But I am not sure whether it is significant enough to go with a seasonal model.

Also, I have updated the question by posting some results based on the original data(non differenced data).

The `auto.arima` model also suggested a `seasonal arima` model for original data.

```
 Best model: ARIMA(0,1,0)(1,0,0)[52]
```

This is the `seasonplot` plot for the original data.

[image]

There is some peak around week 12-13. Will this results enough to go with a `seasonal arima` model?

Any advice would be highly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Consider supplying original (non-differenced) data to `auto.arima`. *However, as you can see based on the time series plot for the first differenced data, there seems to be no seasonal trend in the data.* It is actually quite hard to see. Consider including a seasonal plot; there is a function `seasonplot` or `ggseasonplot` for it in the `forecast` package.

Comment: @RichardHardy  Hi, is it okay, since the data is non-stationary?

Comment: @Sam88, it is OK because `auto.arima` does the differencing for you based on a smart algorithm.

Comment: @RichardHardy  thanks. I am also new to time series forecasting. Do you recommend to do machine learning techniques like rolling cross validation to find the time series model parameters ?

Comment: And if you have daily data, see also [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/225995/deciding-the-value-of-period-in-seasonal-arima-r/226455#226455) regarding long seasonal periods.

Comment: "However, as you can see...for the first differenced data, there seems to be no seasonal trend in the data..."---that's a loose statement made from eyeballing the data. The suggested SARIMA(0,0,0)(1,0,0)[52] model says the series is made up of 52 constituent AR(1) series, one for each week, with a lag of one year. What happens this week depends on what happened the same week last year, plus a disturbance. You may want to consider whether you have clear reason to discount this possibility. A sample simulated from SARIMA(0,0,0)(1,0,0)[52] model would not look very different from your data.

Comment: "I...took the seasonal difference of the first differenced data..."---there's no reason to do this unless you believe the series is seasonally integrated, which does not seem to be the case here for your first differenced data. (To check the SARIMA(0,0,0)(1,0,0)[52] fit, one would apply $1-\phi L^{52}$ to the series, where $\phi$ is the SAR(1) coefficient, then check whiteness of the resulting series.)

Comment: @RichardHardy: do you want to post your comment(s) as an answer? [Better to have a short answer than no answer at all.](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5326/1352) Anyone who has a better answer can post it.

Comment: @Michael: do you want to post your comment(s) as an answer? [Better to have a short answer than no answer at all.](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5326/1352) Anyone who has a better answer can post it.

Comment: You may be interested in the excellent free online book [*Forecasting: Principles and Practice* (2nd ed.) by Athanasopoulos & Hyndman](https://otexts.org/fpp2/).

Comment: @RichardHardy I have updated the question with the seasonal plots. Please have a look if you a time.

Comment: @Michael You have made a very good point. I never thought like that. I have updated the question with the seasonal plots. Do you think what we saw from those plots will be enough to go with a seasonal arima model. ?

Comment: @StephanKolassa I fitted a Seasonal Arima model for this data and the prediction accuracy was very bad. I also fitted a random forest model with lag price (lag=1) as the predictor. The prediction results was very good. Doe the use of random forest model in time series is appropriate ?

Comment: If it works, it works. Did you assess prediction accuracy in-sample or out-of-sample? And which accuracy metric are you using?

Comment: @StephanKolassa Yeah. I used MSE as the metric. In fact I posted another question regarding the comparison of two models. Please have a look if you have time. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/491871/comparing-a-arima-model-with-random-forest-model-for-time-series-data

Comment: MSE is good. Are you using a holdout sample?

Comment: @StephanKolassa Holdout means a validation set isn't it ? Yeah I trained the model using first 200 observations and evaluated it from the rest of the observations